Nginx Proxy Returns 502 and 499 Errors After 6 Days of Running
I have an Nginx proxy configured to cache responses from an external service, but I've been experiencing frequent 502 (Bad Gateway) and 499 (Client Closed Request) errors after approximately 6 days of continuous operation. Restarting the Nginx process temporarily resolves the issue, but the errors reoccur after 6 days.
Here’s my Nginx configuration:
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=the_cache:10m max_size=10m
    inactive=60s use_temp_path=off;

  server {
    listen 80;

    # Cache for /foo/bar only
    location /foo/bar {
      set $cache_key $request_uri;  # Use request URI as the cache key
      # Proxy to the HTTPS backend
      proxy_pass __BACKEND_URL__;
      # Cache configuration for this path
      proxy_cache the_cache;
      proxy_cache_key $cache_key;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 __CACHE_DURATION__;
      proxy_cache_valid any 0;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

    location = /health {
      access_log off;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
      return 200 '{"status":"UP"}';
    }

    # No caching for other paths
    location / {
      proxy_pass __BACKEND_URL__;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 81;
    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      server_tokens on;
    }
  }
}

Resources allocated:
cpu: 256
memory: 512

Snapshot of resource usage after 6 days uptime:
Mem: 883276K used, 66764K free, 616K shrd, 46492K buff, 246676K cached
CPU:   1% usr   0% sys   0% nic  94% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.01 0.08 0.10 2/401 10133
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
 9991    50 root     S    1809m 194%   0   0% /managed-agents/execute-command/ssm-session-worker
   46     1 nginx    S    20544   2%   1   0% nginx: worker process
   50     7 root     S    1889m 203%   1   0% /managed-agents/execute-command/ssm-agent-worker
    7     0 root     S    1805m 194%   0   0% /managed-agents/execute-command/amazon-ssm-agent
   47     1 nginx    S    19948   2%   0   0% nginx: cache manager process
    1     0 root     S    19704   2%   0   0% nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
10000  9991 root     S     1696   0%   0   0% sh
10093 10000 root     T     1664   0%   0   0% vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
10094 10000 root     T     1664   0%   1   0% vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
10097 10000 root     T     1664   0%   0   0% vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
10132 10000 root     R     1624   0%   1   0% top

Questions:
What could be causing the 502 and 499 errors after this duration?
Are there specific configurations or settings I should check or adjust to prevent these errors?
